# Evitar que imagens sejam cortada, entre páginas, ao gerar PDF de um html

Tags: javascript, pdf

Como posso evitar que uma imagem de uma determinada página que salvo como `PDF` seja cortada. como no exemplo abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O arquivo é gerado usando o comando `print`

```
javascript:window.print()
```

Segue meu código html:

```
<html>

    <head>
    <link href="print.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>    
    <title><?=$linha['nivel']?> – 
            <?=$linha['ano']?> 
</title>
</head>
<body>

<!-- Retorna dados da tabela -->
<?php
function criarCombo($table,$id,$valor)
{
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM perguntas";
   $rs_sql = mysql_query($sql);
   while($linha=mysql_fetch_array($rs_sql))
   {
     $chave = $linha[$id];
     $nome  = $linha[$valor];
     $combo = $combo . "<option value=\"$id\">$nome</option>";
   }
   echo $combo;
}
?>


<?php



    // se o número de resultados for maior que zero, mostra os dados
    if($total > 0) {
        // inicia o loop que vai mostrar todos os dados
        do {
?>
            <p><hr><u><b>(<?=$linha['name']?>)</b></u>  
            <?=$linha['nivel']?> – 
            <?=$linha['ano']?> 


             <!-- -- <button><== Remover</button> -- <button>Adicionar ==></button> -->
            <?=$linha['questiontext']?></br>
            <?=$linha['answer']?>
<?php
        // finaliza o loop que vai mostrar os dados
        }while($linha = mysql_fetch_assoc($dados));
    // fim do if 
    }
?>
<a style="display:scroll;position:fixed;top:30px;right:60px;" class="soTela" title='Imprimir conteúdo' href='javascript:window.print()'>Imprimir Prova</a>

</body>
</html>
<?php
// tira o resultado da busca da memória
mysql_free_result($dados);
?>
```

Comment: Incua o html com o CSS

Comment: Talvez a documentação do [`page-break-before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/page-break-before), [`page-break-after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/page-break-after) e [`page-break-inside`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/page-break-inside) te ajudem. E [este artigo](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/page-break/) também

Comment: Não tem CSS, é só a página pura mesmo.

Comment: Lembrando que este erro acontece no firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nesse caso, acredito que você possa alterar o estilo da sua página. No código CSS você pode colocar uma configuração própria para a impressão da página.

```
@media print {
/*Aqui vai seu css*/
}
```

Dentro dessa tag você pode especificações e modo que a página se adapte a uma visualização diferente quando o usuário tentar imprimir a página. Nesse caso, você pode definir um **float** na imagem, assim ela ficará ao lado do texto.

Comment: não é interessante que a imagem fique ao lado do texto, gostaria apenas que ela não se dividisse em páginas diferentes.

Comment: Nesse caso, você pode tentar utilizar o comando `page-break-before` e `page-break-after` do CSS, com ele é possível definir como um elemento deve se comportar no momento da impressão (usando também o comando `@media print`)

Comment: Obrigado aí Lucas Lima!